# Is there a way to dynamically create nested divs onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to create a page where the user is able to customize the form to their needs by adding in extra divs or nested divs (as many layers deep as they'd like). Within each div I'd like to have text input and a button which adds another div on the same level and a button that nests a div within it. Both divs should again have a text input and a button which does the same thing.

However I've gotten a bit stuck. When I attempt to create a nested div I always end up adding it at the very bottom instead of inside its parent.

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 1;
        function addNode() {
            var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            counter++;
            newDiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + counter + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs'>";
            document.getElementById("dynamicInput").appendChild(newDiv);
            var newButton = document.createElement('button');
            newButton.type = "button";
            newButton.onclick = addSub;

            document.getElementById("dynamicInput").appendChild(newButton);
        }
        function addSub() {
            var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            counter++;
            newDiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + counter + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs' style='margin:10px'>";
            document.getElementById("subInput").appendChild(newDiv);
        }
    </script>
    <form class="form" method="POST">
        <div id="dynamicInput" name="dynamicInput" multiple="multiple">
            Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs">
            <div id="subInput" name="subInput" multiple="multiple">
                <input type="button" value="add nested" onClick="addSub();">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addNode();" >
        <input type="submit" value = "answer" multiple="multiple"/>

    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: `addSub` doesn't seem to add any buttons. I believe you want to reorganise your code so that both click handlers call some function to create the div.

Comment: Then, note that `addNode` does exactly the same thing regardless of which button invoked it. And also note that the nested structure is ephemeral: this form as it is will just post all the inputs to the server in a flat list.

Comment: IDs must be unique. You may not have more than 1 element on the page with any given id, doing so renders your page invalid. While the browser may still display it okay, interaction with it will not be as expected. Your code appends the button and the div to an element with a hard-coded id - this can't really work, now can it? You should look into adding handlers with JS, using `.addEventListener` - once this is done, the function that is called can determine which element invoked it, simply by looking at the `this` variable. You can then climb around the DOM tree with `.parentNode` and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete solution for you keep in mind that if you need to bind extra events on your produced inputs and buttons you ll have to do it inside the functions addNode or addSub as i did for the click event on the buttons.

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/r70wqav7/

```js
var counter = 1;
function addNode(element) {
 counter++;
  var new_entry="Entry "+counter+"<br><input type='text' name='myInputs'><br>";
  element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin",new_entry);
}
function addSub(element) {
 counter++;
 var new_sub_entry="<div class='block'>"
          +"Entry "+counter+"<br><input type='text' name='myInputs'><br>"
                  +"<div class='buttons'>"
                  +"<input class='add_sub_button' type='button' value='add nested'>"
                  +"<input class='add_button' type='button' value='Add another text input' >"
                  +"</div>"
                  +"</div><br />"
                  +"</div>";
  element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin",new_sub_entry); 
  var blocks=element.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("block");
  blocks[blocks.length-1].getElementsByClassName("add_sub_button")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
   addSub(this.parentNode);
  });
  blocks[blocks.length-1].getElementsByClassName("add_button")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
   addNode(this.parentNode);
  });
}

var buttons=document.getElementsByClassName("add_button");
for(i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
 buttons[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    addNode(this.parentNode);
  });
}
var nested_buttons=document.getElementsByClassName("add_sub_button");
for(i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
 nested_buttons[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    addSub(this.parentNode);
  });
}
```

```css
div.block{
  padding:5px;
  border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" method="POST">
  <div class="block">
        Entry 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs"><br>
        <div class="buttons">
          <input class="add_sub_button" type="button" value="add nested">
          <input class="add_button" type="button" value="Add another text input" >
        </div>
  </div><br />
        <input type="submit" value = "answer" multiple="multiple"/>
</form>
```

**EDITED : There was an error binding the click event on nested items updated to work properly**

Answer (score 1):

Here's another worked example which makes use of the concepts I mentioned in an earlier comment. I've moved the Add-Item button outside the form and altered the method used to determine the text for each new item added. Rather than keep a counter, I count the number of existing items in the document and increment it, using this as as the n in the string "Entry n"

I should have added(appended) the sub-item before the button that creates new ones, but was lazy and just called `appendChild` on the button after the other new element was added - the end result is the same, but it's less efficient and will cause slower performance/shorter battery life.

I was going to use the `.cloneNode` method of the `.dynamicInput` div, when clicking "Add new item", however this will copy all subitems of the chosen target and we still need to call `addEventListener` for the button anyway, so I've opted to simply create each input-item added with the "Add new item" button instead.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementById(id);}
function allByClass(className,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByClassName(className);}
function allByTag(tagName,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByTagName(tagName);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    byId('addNewInputBtn').addEventListener('click', myAddNewItem, false);
    var subItemBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.dynamicInput button')[0];
    subItemBtn.addEventListener('click', myAddSubItem, false);
}

function makeNewItem(titleStr)
{
    var div = newEl('div');
    div.className = 'dynamicInput';

    var heading = newEl('h3');
    heading.innerText = titleStr;
    div.appendChild(heading);

    var input = newEl('input');
    div.appendChild(input);

    var btn = newEl('button');
    btn.innerText = 'Add sub-items';
    btn.addEventListener('click', myAddSubItem, false);
    div.appendChild(btn);

    return div;
}


function myAddNewItem(evt)
{
    var numAlreadyExisting = allByClass('dynamicInput').length;             // count number of divs with className = dynamicInput
    var newNum = numAlreadyExisting + 1;
    var newInputPanel = makeNewItem('Entry ' + newNum);
    byId('myForm').appendChild(newInputPanel);
    return false;
}

function myAddSubItem(evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();                                                   // stops this button causing the form to be submitted
    var clickedBtn = this;
    var inputDiv = clickedBtn.parentNode;
    var newInput = newEl('input');
    inputDiv.appendChild(newInput);
    inputDiv.appendChild(clickedBtn);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='myForm'>
        <div class='dynamicInput'>
         <h3>Entry 1</h3>
         <input type='text'/><button>Add sub-item</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <button id='addNewInputBtn'>Add new item</button>
</body>
</html>
```